Snappy PDF Binary not Found when it exists on Docker

code
: 
127
message
: 
"The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:\nstderr: \"sh: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: not found\n\"\nstdout: \"\"\ncommand: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --margin-bottom '20' '/tmp/knp_snappy667359d51aa855.19995961.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy667359d51ab013.97837623.pdf'."
status_code
: 
500

I have checked the path on docker.
I have verified that the binaries are correctly copied to the Docker container during the build process and have ensured that the permissions are set correctly. However, the PDF library is still unable to access the wkhtmltopdf binary.
Check the files, please, and let me know what is going on. I have Laravel 9 with php 8.0.30
DockerFile
FROM laravelphp/vapor:php81
COPY vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY . /var/task
RUN which wkhtmltopdf-amd64

Snappy.php Config File:
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Snappy PDF / Image Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option contains settings for PDF generation.
    |
    | Enabled:
    |
    |    Whether to load PDF / Image generation.
    |
    | Binary:
    |
    |    The file path of the wkhtmltopdf / wkhtmltoimage executable.
    |
    | Timout:
    |
    |    The amount of time to wait (in seconds) before PDF / Image generation is stopped.
    |    Setting this to false disables the timeout (unlimited processing time).
    |
    | Options:
    |
    |    The wkhtmltopdf command options. These are passed directly to wkhtmltopdf.
    |    See https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt for all options.
    |
    | Env:
    |
    |    The environment variables to set while running the wkhtmltopdf process.
    |
    */

    'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  =>'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env' => array(),
    ],
];


"unable to access the wkhtmltopdf binary" - what does that mean? Did you check whether the file /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 really exists during runtime? How is this problem related to PHP, Laravel, or Snappy, regarding the error message you've added?
